# Gerrit plugin gitilte installation issues

Tags: plugins, ubuntu-16.04, gerrit

Newbie setup Gitiles plugin at ubuntu 16.04
~/gerrit/plugins$ buck build gitiles
and send the error below

```
BUILD FAILED: Buck wasn't able to parse    /home/gerrit2/gerrit/plugins/gitiles/BUCK: IOError: [Errno 2] No such    file or directory:    '/home/gerrit2/gerrit/plugins/bucklets/gerrit_plugin.bucklet' Call   stack: File "/home/gerrit2/buck/python-dsl/buck_parser/buck.py", line    1102, in process_with_diagnostics diagnostics=diagnostics) File    "/home/gerrit2/buck/python-dsl/buck_parser/buck.py", line 993, in    process os.path.join(self._project_root, path)) File    "/home/gerrit2/buck/python-dsl/buck_parser/buck.py", line 987, in   
_process_build_file return self._process(build_env, path, is_implicit_include=False) File    "/home/gerrit2/buck/python-dsl/buck_parser/buck.py", line 947, in   
_process exec(code, module.__dict__) File "/home/gerrit2/gerrit/plugins/gitiles/BUCK", line 1    include_defs('//bucklets/gerrit_plugin.bucklet') File    "/home/gerrit2/buck/python-dsl/buck_parser/buck.py", line 750, in   
_include_defs inner_env, mod = self._process_include(path, is_implicit_include) File    "/home/gerrit2/buck/python-dsl/buck_parser/buck.py", line 961, in   
_process_include return self._process(build_env, path, is_implicit_include=is_implicit_include) File    "/home/gerrit2/buck/python-dsl/buck_parser/buck.py", line 936, in   
_process with open(path, 'r') as f:
```

========================================================================
any idea about this log?
tks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to build the Gitiles plugin? You can download the plugin from [GerritForge](https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/).

- Search for plugin-gitiles-stable-GERRIT-VERSION
- Download the gitiles.jar file
- Install it at GERRIT-SITE/plugins
- Restart Gerrit